# How to force a #vuetify #treeview node reload?

Tags: vue.js, treeview, vuetify.js, treenode

Using #vuetify #Treeview in #vue.js project, there is no example on how to reload edited node or how to update parent of deleted node.
If any sample or any help link?

Comment: It should update nodes automatically, but you can try calling `.updateAll()`

Comment: @Styx At the moment we converted tree data model from json to string and back to json, so that the tree is forced to reload it, but this is not a wise way, if you agree. They should'v predicted a method to call, correct?

Comment: Yes, they should have. Btw, you can force reload without converting to/from string/json: `this.$set(this, 'treeModel', Object.assign({}, this.treeModel))`

Comment: You are right, this way is possible too, since the tree is big one, reloading all will effect app performance and change collapse state of user tree. In other components it is possible to call any particular node and say reload from this node. How is it possible here?

Comment: You could provide minimal example of the issue in a codepen to get more traction.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue I wanted to remove the active item from the v-treeview.
I use logical deletes so my code looks like this.  This requires no manual refreshing of the tree view or any weird object assign calls

When clicking on a tree node it gets put into active[0]

```
<v-btn @click="deleteNode()">delete</v-btn>

deleteNode() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")) {
        this.active[0].status = "Deleted"; //flag as deleted
        this.active.splice(0, 1); //remove from active array
        this.removeDeleted(this, this.items); now remove it from the bound array
    }
}

removeDeleted(me, currentArray) {
      const delItems = [];
      currentArray.forEach(element => {
        if (element.status == "Deleted") {
          delItems.push(element);
        }
        if (
          element.children != undefined &&
          element.children != null &&
          element.children.length > 0
        ) {
          me.removeDeleted(me, element.children);
        }
      });
      delItems.forEach(item => {
        currentArray.splice(currentArray.indexOf(item), 1);
      });
    },
```